# Calculating the range (proximity) of a ship taking into acount coastlines

Tags: python, geospatial

I have speed and location (lon, lat) data of ships at sea. I would like to calculate which (if any) cities could be reached by a ship in a known period (say 1 hour).

I need to take the coastline geometry into consideration during the calculation. For example, if the city is 10 km away from the ships position, it could be reached within an hour if the ship is travelling at 10 km h-1 (I know ships use knots...this is just an example) 'as the crow flies'. However, given the coastline geometry, the ship has to move around the peninsula (blue arrows), thus putting the city out of range for the same time window.

I'm not asking people to write the code (I like the challenge of that myself), but does anybody have any pointers of where to start with this sort of problem in python? I have looked through some of the ESRI toolboxes (Network analyst, proximity tools etc.) and geopandas, shapely, fiona but struggling with an answer to my needs. I'll be using a geopandas database of ship and city positions. I can use the natural earth shapefiles, or geojsons for the land. If the problem can be solved with native python libraries that would be amazing.

I'm looking for libraries or ideas as to how I might tackle this problem.

[image]